# How to read the path that a broken symbolic link points to?

Tags: java

If `symlink` is a File object that corresponds to a symbolic link, then:

```
File target = symlink.getCanonicalPath();
```

… succeeds in returning the target that it is pointing to. `Paths#toRealPath()` also works in the same situation.

However, if the symbolic link is broken (dangling), both of the above APIs fail to return a `File` (or `Path`) representing the (non-existing) thing that it's pointing to.

I am writing a tool that needs to be able to read those values, even for dangling symlinks. What API do I use to obtain the file or directory that a symlink points at (regardless of whether the symlink is correct or broken)?

## update

Based on the accepted answer, one can obtain the target of the symlink (even a broken one) using:

```
Path target = Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/some/directory/symlink"));
```

… if `target` is then relative, you can de-reference it based on the location where the symlink itself is found by doing the following:

```
Paths.get("/some/directory/symlink").resolveSibling(".").resolve(target);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use java's nio file system api:

```
Path target = Files.readSymbolicLink(Paths.get("/symlink"));
```

[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readSymbolicLink(java.nio.file.Path)) stipulates that "the target of the link need not exist".